# Calling a function that was defined by exec() from an object in another class. Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm new to Python, and would appreciate some help getting out of the namespace hell I've created for myself...

Background:
Using web.py on a Raspberry Pi to receive user generated code from a blockly web-app.

Code is then executed in a function that is a member of the iforge class using exec()

User code can often contain functions.

User code can also spawn threads using the myThread class.

So... If user code defines a function and then spawns a thread, and that thread wants to call the user-defined function, I need to fingure out how to pass a pointer to that function into the thread object. Now when I do it, it says it doesn't recognize the name.

Here is the class that receives the user code and executes it:

```
class iforge:
def GET(self):
  return "You have found the code executor function"

def POST(self):
    global _shutdown,GPIO,time
    cleanup()       
    web.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    web.header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    request=web.input()
    code=request.code
    exec (code,globals(),locals())
    reply={'message':'now running your code on rPi'}
    return json.dumps(reply)
```

Here is the code that handles the thread creation:

```
class myThread (threading.Thread):
def __init__(self, threadName, code, caller):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.name = threadName
    self.code = code
    self.shutdown = False
    self.caller= caller
def run(self):
    from iforge import *
    global _shutdown,GPIO,time
    print "Starting thread"
    l=dir(self.caller.POST)
    print "printing debug info"
    print self.caller
    print dir(self.caller.POST)
    method=getattr(self.caller, self.code[:-2])
    while not _shutdown:
        pass
        exec(method(), globals(),locals())
    print "Exiting thread"
```

Here is a sample of the user code that would get sent to iforge.POST:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(1, GPIO.OUT)
def do_something():
  GPIO.output(1, GPIO.HIGH)
thread1 = myThread('if_myThread','''do_something()''',self)
thread1.start()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by passing the globals() functon to exec as BOTH the globals and locals argument to exec.

So in the Post() function when I call exec, I use 
     exec (code,globals(),globals())